# Excel, append one full range to the end of another in one full column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of data in Excel in different sheets. I would like to add a third column in another sheet, which combines the first and second. How can I do this with a formula such that I can add or remove data from columns A in the sheet 1 and B in the sheet 2 without ever having to touch column C in the sheet 3?

I would like to copy the whole column  for example:

```
=append(SheetName1!A:A ,SheetName2!A:A)
```

Is that possible?

**EDITED**: I'm having a problem with Excel 365, I'm using Manjaro Linux, so I'm working in the chrome browser. The problem is that I have one excel file with 10 sheets in it. I want to get columns A B C and D from 9 sheets and append them in one big table on sheet 10.

**Sheet1:**

```
Tarefa  Atividade   Importante  Urgente Numero-Total-de-Tarefas 
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
```

**Sheet2:**

```
Tarefa  Atividade   Importante  Urgente Numero-Total-de-Tarefas 
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
```

And the same thing for the other 7 tables.

I want to get all these 9 tables and append them into the `sheet10`
like:
**Sheet10**

```
Tarefa  Atividade   Importante  Urgente Numero-Total-de-Tarefas 
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
A          1           asd         fg         gh
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
B          1           asd         fg         gh
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
C          1           asd         fg         gh
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
D         ...          ...         ...        ...
D         ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
...       ...          ...         ...        ...
```

The [file Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtPc07fC4Qqyj-Rc6kRVDySsgrdQZA?e=rh3r0J)
**Edited:**
I guess it's my office with the @SpectralInstance formula:
it's getting a result like this:
[image] That's the only explanation
Thanks a lot, guys

Comment: As you haven't specified an Excel version, please see this article https://medium.com/swlh/combining-multiple-tables-into-one-c21aa5bdf36f

Comment: @SpectralInstance (or others) How to check Excel version? I have Excel for microsoft 365, which has `XFILTER` but not `VSTACK` or `LET` functions, below answers are referring to "newest" version of excel and office 365, is office 365 different than microsoft 365?

Comment: @tnavidi, if you have 365 then do you have FILTER(no x) and LET - you will only have the others (VSTACK) etc, if you deliberately opted-in to the Insiders program (that option is is displayed on your File-> Account page)

Comment: @tnavidi, I just saw your comment about LAMBDA, everyone on 365 should have it, as it went GA last year - if you don't then it's because of policy restrictions in your organisation

Comment: @SpectralInstance Thanks, I'm missing the insider button, probably due to policy restrictions as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula below (adapted from the link I posted in my comment)

```
=LET(one,Sheet1!A1:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)),two,Sheet2!A1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)),IFERROR(INDEX(one,SEQUENCE(ROWS(one)+ROWS(two))),INDEX(two,SEQUENCE(ROWS(one)+ROWS(two))-ROWS(one))))
```

will work in Excel online, as illustrated in this (read-only) [file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au1B_SIN8RJg4-wMIr1h61BZhPATFQ?e=YXhXFy).

**EDIT 4-May-2022**

Based on your updated, and *dramatically* different, specification, this formula, as well as filling half the screen, will take all data from Sheet1, including the headers, and the header-exclusive data from Sheets 2 through 9, and consolidate them:

```
=LET(t_1,Sheet1!A1:INDEX(Sheet1!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet1!E:E)),t_2,Sheet2!A2:INDEX(Sheet2!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet2!E:E)),
t_3,Sheet3!A2:INDEX(Sheet3!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet3!E:E)),t_4,Sheet4!A2:INDEX(Sheet4!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet4!E:E)),
t_5,Sheet5!A2:INDEX(Sheet5!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet5!E:E)),t_6,Sheet6!A2:INDEX(Sheet6!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet6!E:E)),
t_7,Sheet7!A2:INDEX(Sheet7!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet7!E:E)),t_8,Sheet8!A2:INDEX(Sheet8!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet8!E:E)),
t_9,Sheet9!A2:INDEX(Sheet9!F:F,COUNTA(Sheet9!E:E)),width,SEQUENCE(,6),

IFERROR(INDEX(t_1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)),width),
IFERROR(INDEX(t_2,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)+ROWS(t_2))-ROWS(t_1),width),
IFERROR(INDEX(t_3,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)+ROWS(t_2)+ROWS(t_3))-ROWS(t_1)-ROWS(t_2),width),
IFERROR(INDEX(t_4,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)+ROWS(t_2)+ROWS(t_3)+ROWS(t_4))-ROWS(t_1)-ROWS(t_2)-ROWS(t_3),width),
IFERROR(INDEX(t_5,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)+ROWS(t_2)+ROWS(t_3)+ROWS(t_4)+ROWS(t_5))-ROWS(t_1)-ROWS(t_2)-ROWS(t_3)-ROWS(t_4),width),
IFERROR(INDEX(t_6,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)+ROWS(t_2)+ROWS(t_3)+ROWS(t_4)+ROWS(t_5)+ROWS(t_6))-ROWS(t_1)-ROWS(t_2)-ROWS(t_3)-ROWS(t_4)-ROWS(t_5),width),
IFERROR(INDEX(t_7,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)+ROWS(t_2)+ROWS(t_3)+ROWS(t_4)+ROWS(t_5)+ROWS(t_6)+ROWS(t_7))-ROWS(t_1)-ROWS(t_2)-ROWS(t_3)-ROWS(t_4)-ROWS(t_5)-ROWS(t_6),width),
IFERROR(INDEX(t_8,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)+ROWS(t_2)+ROWS(t_3)+ROWS(t_4)+ROWS(t_5)+ROWS(t_6)+ROWS(t_7)+ROWS(t_8))-ROWS(t_1)-ROWS(t_2)-ROWS(t_3)-ROWS(t_4)-ROWS(t_5)-ROWS(t_6)-ROWS(t_7),width),
INDEX(t_9,SEQUENCE(ROWS(t_1)+ROWS(t_2)+ROWS(t_3)+ROWS(t_4)+ROWS(t_5)+ROWS(t_6)+ROWS(t_7)+ROWS(t_8)+ROWS(t_9))-ROWS(t_1)-ROWS(t_2)-ROWS(t_3)-ROWS(t_4)-ROWS(t_5)-ROWS(t_6)-ROWS(t_7)-ROWS(t_8),width)
)))))))))
```

Comment: In this case you have to know the cell value, in my case didn't work

Comment: @user2535338 please clarify, I don't know what you mean by 'cell value' - you can see from the link that the formula works online ?

Comment: `one` and `two` are the variables, aren't they? In my excel didn't worked

Comment: Yes, they're variables - you would have to adjust them if your tabs aren't called Sheet1 and Sheet2...

Comment: So I've done it correctly, but my excel didn't recognize the formula

Comment: Please post the formula you've used, and clarify what your tab names are (or, better yet, post a link to your actual file)

Comment: Added the file, I want to append the sheet1 to sheet9 in sheet10, they can vary the in size

Comment: Updated my answer based on your 'clarification'

Comment: I think that my office 365 is not the same. for me here is not appearing anything, just a red rectangle around the cell formula

Comment: Excel for the web is not Office 365 and, to my knowledge, is the same for everyone (who doesn't have a business account) - please update the linked file (in your OP) with the formula, and then I will have a look

Comment: Updated the file. can you access it?

Comment: Yes, but I can't edit the file. Can you make a copy of your file, one that is editable for me, then I'll see if I can get that copy working ?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtPc07fC4Qqyj-Rc6kRVDySsgrdQZA?e=Lgb1WZ try this one

Comment: Ok, I've updated it - please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244516/discussion-between-user2535338-and-spectralinstance).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible with the newest Excel functions:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=VSTACK(TOCOL(A:A,1),TOCOL(D:D,1))
```

You can now remove/add values in either column to your liking without having to adjust the formula in `F1`.

Comment: `=VSTACK(TOCOL(Sheet1!A:A,1),TOCOL(Sheet2!A:A,1))` Formula in the `Sheet3 A1` doesn't work

Comment: @user2535338, you probably don't have access to these new functions yet. I assume you recieve the `#NAME` error. You'd need ms365's BETA-channel for insiders to use the above.

Comment: How do I sign up to have access to this function?

Comment: @user2535338 see [here](https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/windows)

Comment: I have to use windows to do that, haven't I?  I'm using manjaro linux, I've found any thing in the browser

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know your version of Excel. So if you don't have access to Early Adopters, but you are Office 365, you can do:

```
=LET( a, A:A, b, B:B,
        fa, FILTER( a, NOT(ISBLANK(a))), fb, FILTER( b, NOT(ISBLANK(b))),
        ra, ROWS(fa), rb, ROWS(fb),
        rSeq, SEQUENCE(ra + rb),
        IFERROR( INDEX( fa, rSeq), INDEX( fb, rSeq - ra )  ) )
```

where **a** and **b** are the columns you want to append.

[image]

Comment: `fa` and `fb` is the `sheetA` and `sheetB`? I'm in office 365

Comment: @user2535338 Actually, **fa** and **fb** are calculated variables from **a** and **b**. So, **a** would be `SheetName1!A:A` and **b** would be `SheetName2!A:A`. Let **fa** and **fb** stay as they are - they are the filters of a and b.

Comment: I've used the following equasion  `=LET( 'Sheet1'!A:A, A:A, 'sheet2'!A:A, A:A,
        fa, FILTER( a, NOT(ISBLANK(a))), fb, FILTER( b, NOT(ISBLANK(b))),
        ra, ROWS(fa), rb, ROWS(fb),
        rSeq, SEQUENCE(ra + rb),
        IFERROR( INDEX( fa, rSeq), INDEX( fb, rSeq - ra )  ) )` and it just stayed the same

Comment: @user2535338 to use Marks answer, you need to replace the addresses for `a` and `b` but leave the identifiers as they are, ie `=LET( a, 'Sheet1'!A:A, b, 'Sheet2'!A:A, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this formula, I've assumed the two columns are A and B:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A:A,B:B)&"</s></t>","//s")
```

[image]

The FilterXML opens for other functionality as well, which you can explore here: [Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/11469519)

(My excel doesn't have the lambda functionality as described in some of the other answers)