# Lookup values from Sheet A with data at Sheet B. The data at sheet B is located in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup, xlookup

[image: Sheet A]

The Sheet A contains data in a single column

[image]

Sheet B contains values in multiple columns and rows

[image]

I would like to find out if the value in Sheet A is present in Sheet B. If the value exists, it should result as 'match'. If the value doesn't exists then should result as 'No match

Comment: You can try to transform the data in sheet B into one column list:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093701/excel-append-one-full-range-to-the-end-of-another-in-one-full-column  or TEXTJOIN all cells into one string to be searched against (depending on the size of the range: “ If the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), TEXTJOIN returns the #VALUE! error.”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may **try** this way, using either `SUM()` or `SUMPRODUCT()` or `MAX()` with `ROW()` Function

[image]

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=--(MAX((A2='Sheet B'!$A$2:$F$7)*ROW('Sheet B'!$A$2:$F$7))>0)
```

The above formula returns a **Boolean Logic** which is turned into `1` & `0` using a `double unary`. And then custom formatted as

```
[=1]"Match";[=0]"No Match";
```

• Perhaps you can wrap the above within an `IF()` as well, in cell `C2`

```
=IF(MAX((A2='Sheet B'!$A$2:$F$7)*ROW('Sheet B'!$A$2:$F$7))>0,"Match","No Match")
```

**Note:** Since its an array formula, based on your excel version need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> , **O365** & **Excel 2021** Users don't need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>!